# Plotting Surfaces With 3 Symbolic Variables

Tags: matlab, plot

First, I need to state that I'm not exactly a math lover or an avid Matlab user. This is college homework that I have been trying to solve for the last 3 hours with no luck. I have googled like crazy, even asked for help via Facebook (where I got replies, but nothing that solved my questions).

This is my first time using this software and I need to graph some things really quick. But no matter how much I read I keep getting syntax errors and the like.

Basically, I have this equation:

```
4*x^2 + y^2 + z^2 - 8*x + 2*y + 3 = 0
```

And I'm trying to plot it/graph it. I thought it would be very straightforward but I'm having problems doing it.

Google searches have shown me the functions ezplot() and ezsurf(), but:

When I do ezplot('4*x^2 + y^2 + z^2 - 8*x + 2*y + 3'), I get the following error:

```
??? Error using ==> char
Cell elements must be character arrays.
Error in ==> ezplot at 158
      fmsg = char(f);
```

And when I do ezsurf('4*x^2 + y^2 + z^2 - 8*x + 2*y + 3')

```
The expression 4*x^2 + y^2 + z^2 - 8*x + 2*y + 3 must only have 2 symbolic variables
Error in ==> ezgraph3>surfplot at 526
[F,var] = ezfixfun(F,fargs,flabel);
Error in ==> ezgraph3 at 49
   [dummy,h] = surfplot(f,domain,surfstyle,cax,Npts,fixdomain,flabel,fargs);
Error in ==> ezsurf at 65
    h = ezgraph3('surf',args{:});
```

Again, this is really my first time using this software. The teacher didn't give us any explanation so I have no idea of what these errors are supposed to mean, let alone solving them. I have no idea of what I'm doing or what I am supposed to do.

I have tried using solve() to solve for 'z' first and then plot the two results I get.

```
s = solve('4*x^2 + y^2 + z^2 - 8*x + 2*y + 3', 'z')
s =
   -(- 4*x^2 + 8*x - y^2 - 2*y - 3)^(1/2)
    (- 4*x^2 + 8*x - y^2 - 2*y - 3)^(1/2)
```

But that's not working either. When I use ezplot() it tells me to use ezsurf, and when I use ezsurf() it tells me about a variable "h" that I have never even declared:

```
>> ezsurf('-(- 4*x^2 + 8*x - y^2 - 2*y - 3)^(1/2)', '(- 4*x^2 + 8*x - y^2 - 2*y - 3)^(1/2)')
??? Undefined function or variable "h".
Error in ==> ezgraph3 at 66
    hh = h;
Error in ==> ezsurf at 65
    h = ezgraph3('surf',args{:});
```

Any help plotting that will be really appreciated. My head is going to explode because people have been telling me this is supposed to be really straightforward.

Thank you!

Comment: If you feel I have satisfactorily answered the question then please mark the response answered. If not, then please let me know why, and I can attempt to improve my answer. Thanks.

Comment: Oh, sorry about that. I managed to solve it on my own. Don't remember what I did but I will mark yours as accepted anyway.

Comment: No worries, I figured it was probably something like that. Sorry my answer wasn't more timely :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works for me:

```
ezsurf('(8*x - 4*x^2 - y^2 - 2*y -3)^(1/2)');
```

Note that `ezsurf` accepts a function of 2 dimensions (that maps into a 3rd dimension). So you must express the function in the form f(x, y) = blah, where blah is what you want as your input to `ezsurf`. All I did was re-arrange your function into the form z = blah, and then input blah to `ezsurf`.

Oh, and two other things, 1) The resulting graph only tells half the story, since the square root of z^2 can be z or minus z (by default, matlab takes the positive square root). 2) The function as above can only be analyzed without complex numbers (such as I've done here) for a very restricted domain of `x` and `y`.